# NSUserDefaults returns NSArray instead of NSDictionary. Apparently since iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the login procedures in my App i am looping through a server response and save some data in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSMutableArray *unitTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[unitTypeArray addObject:@{@"Name":@"Item",
                                   @"Description":@"Item",
                                   @"ID":@"0",
                                   @"Time":@"2014-12-29 12:00:00",
                                   @"AddedByUserID":@"2",
                                   @"Depth":@"0",
                                   @"Height":@"0",
                                   @"Width":@"0",
                                   @"softLimit":@"10"}];

for (NSMutableDictionary *unitType in response) {
    [unitType setValue:@10 forKey:@"softLimit"];
    [unitTypeArray addObject:unitType];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:unitTypeArray forKey:@"unitTypes"];
```

Later i am retrieving this Array:

```
self.unitTypeArr = [[self.preferences objectForKey:@"unitTypes"] mutableCopy];
```

but i am getting a NSDictionary back. This was perfectly working in iOS < 9.0 but since iOS 9.0 my app is crashing. Is there a fix for that or do i have to convert the NSDictionary to NSArray?

Comment: What is the crash message ?

Comment: The crash message is:
    [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  For instance, what is self.preferences?  Just a cached reference to [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]?  What's the code that is referencing an objectAtIndex?  It might be significant that the unitTypeArray is an array of dictionary objects - maybe you're trying to read out of an object you took from that array instead of the array itself, perhaps?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is setting a value for "unitTypes"? Can you show a complete, minimal code example?

Comment: The above code seems fine. Either you are setting the `unitTypes` from some other place or the error is not happening from some other place. What is `self.preferences` ? What happens if you replace `self.preferences` with `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` ?

Comment: To set a single value for key in a dictionary use always `setObject:forKey:` or still better subscripting. The KVC method `setValue:forKey:` has a different meaning, which could cause unexpected behavior in a non-KVC context.

Comment: On login completion i am running the code shown above. Nothing more. In the Settings i am first retrieving the Array:
    self.preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.unitTypeArr = [[self.preferences objectForKey:@"unitTypes"] mutableCopy];
self.preferences and self.unitTypeArr are properties of the NSUserDefaults and NSMutableArray. Then i want to use the content os self.unitTypeArr to fill a UITableView, wich is creating the crash:
    lblUnitType.text = [[self.unitTypeArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];

Answer (score 1):

you are saving **unitTypeArray** into **NSUserDefault**. right? as it's type **NSMutableArray**; So, you will get **Array** from **preference**. Why you expecting **NSDictionary**?

Retrieve Data by this way

```
NSMutableArray *unitTypeArr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"unitTypes"];
```

Comment: Because i am getting NSDictionary back:
![nsdictionary](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gski7g9ulci4fd3/Screenshot%202015-10-19%2023.03.22.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get it going. The first code block in my question was only run if the data hasn't been retrieved before. I can't understand why, but if i run this every time on login, it is working. Even though it contains exactly the same data.